# Finding mean from die probability

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

> Example 4.4.5: Suppose that there is a 6-sided die that is weighted in
>   such a way that each time the die is rolled, the probabilities of
>   rolling any of the numbers from 1 to 5 are all equal, but the
>   probability of rolling a 6 is twice the probability of roll- ing a 1.
>   When you roll the die once, the 6 outcomes are not equally likely.
>   What are the probabilities of the 6 outcomes?

***On the basis of the above question  a question has been asked to evaluate the mean.***
[image]

My problem is that, when they  evaluate the mean, they multiplied with the probability by 1, 2 ,  3  , 4 , 5 and  6 why?  In die , all are they equal probable.

Comment: mean is $\sum_i Y_i P(Y_i)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean of a discrete random variable is defined as

$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum\limits_{x\in X} xp(x)$$

In this case $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, so that's where you are getting the multiplication. You can think of the probabilities as weighting the importance of each of these $6$ numbers.

Comment: The question is about 6 sided die. So the  probability of 6 can be 2/7 and this is not saying that there are 6 possibilities that we can have 6 from the die or  5 possibilities that we can have 5. We only have  one 6, one 5 , one 4 etc on the die.

Comment: @ComplexGuy What is your definition of 'mean'? We are not saying that $\dfrac{2}{7}$ happens six times - it doesn't even happen one time. We are saying that $6$ happens two-sevenths of the time.

Comment: 6 happens two-sevenths of the time. But why do you multiply the 6 with the 2/7? Let an apple happens two-sevenths of the time   then will we multiply the apple with the probability? 

Sorry i have misunderstood in it this is why i am clearing my concept

Comment: @ComplexGuy Well, if an apple happened two-sevenths of the time, and nothing happened the other five-sevenths of the time, your the mean over the time would be two-sevenths of the apple. If an orange happened the other five-sevenths, then your (fruit) mean would be two-sevenths of an apple and five-sevenths of an orange. 'The mean' intuitively means what you are expecting to roll. Perhaps you are getting it confused with the [arithmetic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean). Here we are talking about a [weighted arithmetic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_average).

Comment: ^where the sum of the weights is equal to $1$. Also take a look at [the expected value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) page - this is what you have been asked to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter stated, to calculate the mean, you multiply each outcome (the number that you roll) by the probability of getting that roll, and add those products up.

On a *regular* or *fair* die, yes, the probabilities of each outcome are the same.  But this isn't a fair die; $6$ is twice as probable as each of the other numbers.

For a fair die, $$E(X) = \frac{1}{6}(1) + \frac{1}{6}(2) + \frac{1}{6}(3) + \frac{1}{6}(4) + \frac{1}{6}(5) + \frac{1}{6}(6) = 3.5.$$

For the unfair die in your problem, $E(X)$ is as calculated.

Comment: $E(X) = \frac{1}{6}(6) + \frac{1}{6}(3) + \frac{1}{4}(4) + \frac{1}{6}(2) + \frac{1}{6}(5) + \frac{1}{6}(1) $Can we write like this? 

What does the X represent?

Comment: $X$ is your random variable.  As for what you wrote in the comment, you have a typo with the $1/4$.  The sum of the probabilities $p(x)$ must be $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The best and naivest way to understand this is to imagine a 7 sided dice with 2 faces holding the value 6. By the definition of the mean you multiply each element of the set by it's probability ... hence 1/7 to each.